# Intrinsic parity of fermions and anti-fermions: why are they opposite?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, fermions, parity

Is there any reason as to why we assign **opposite** parities to fermions and anti-fermions?

As far as I know, the only theoretical reason is that this is what [Dirac's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation) predicts, but this seems very limited in my opinion. I was wondering if, on a more fundamental level, this could be deduced from the properties of the [Lorentz Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group) or the [spin-statistic theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin%E2%80%93statistics_theorem)$^{[1]}$.

In the same spirit, is there any reason to assign the **same** parity to bosons and anti-bosons? Again, is this just a convention, or does it follow from some fundamental requirement, like Lorentz invariance?

---

$^{[1]}$ or even the [CPT theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPT_symmetry). This would be slightly contrived and roundabout in my opinion, but it is certainly more fundamental than Dirac's equation.

Comment: It's because of locality. It is very nicely explained in Weinberg's textbook on qft vol.1 chapter 5

Comment: More on [intrinsic parity](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%22intrinsic+parity%22). Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/156779/2451

Answer (score 4):

If you consider the Dirac field $\psi$ as a linear combination of the particle annihilation part $\psi^+$ and the antiparticle creation part $\psi^{-c}$, then we have the requirement that $P\psi(x)P^{-1}$ should be proportional to $\psi(Px)$, where $P$ is the parity/space inversion operator. (I commit a slight abuse of notation here - the $P$ is both the unitary operator representing parity acting on the space of states and the space inversion operator on Minkowski space sending $(t,\vec x)$ to $(t,-\vec x)$ in the argument.

In general, we have also that this should hold for $\psi^+$ and $\psi^{-c}$, i.e.
\begin{align}
P \psi^+(x)P^{-1} & = \eta^\ast b_u \psi^+(Px) \\
P \psi^{-c}(x)P^{-1} & = \eta^c b_v \psi^{-c}(Px)
\end{align}
where the $\eta^\ast$ and $\eta^c$ are the phases by which the anti-creation /annihilation operators transform and the $b_{u/v}$ are the phases by which the fundamental spinors traditionally denoted as $u_s,v_s$ transform. These formulae come about because e.g. $\psi^+(x) = \sum_s \int u_s(\vec p) \exp(-\mathrm{i}px)a_s(\vec p)\mathrm{d}^3p$ schematically, and likewise for $\psi^{-c}$. One can then show that $b_u = -b_v$, and for $P\psi(x)P^{-1}$ to be propertional to $\psi(Px)$ we must then have that $\eta^\ast = -\eta^c$ because otherwise $\psi(x) = c_1 \psi^+(x) + c_2 \psi^{-c}$ cannot be proportional because the relative sign would change under parity.

For a more detailed derivation, see *"The quantum theory of fields"* by Weinberg, volume 1, section 5.5 as suggested in a comment by TwoBs.

Comment: (1/2) speaking of contrived and roundabout proofs :-P I don't find this 100% satisfactory, for several reasons: just by considering a Dirac field we are assuming properties about parity (because we are using the sum of left- and right-handed fields; the bispinor representation comes with a very natural parity matrix $\gamma^0$, and by using it you are tacitly assuming that parity is conserved, otherwise there is no reason not to include, say, a "mass term" $m'\bar\psi\gamma^5\psi$). Moreover, this is based on a "field formalism" instead of the raw properties of particles and the Lorentz group.

Comment: (2/2) Also, your discussion seems to be particular to free fields (or asymptotic), and is not directly applicable to fermionic bound states. What's more, to me it is not obvious how to generalise this analysis to higher half-interger spin representations, where there isn't a natural candidate for the parity matrix, and the fields are always gauge fields (so that everything is more complex). I guess I had hoped that something much more direct would imply that anti-fermions have opposite parity, instead of having to rely on fields, creation/annihilation operators, locality, and all that jazz...

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform You cannot expect to use any arguments about representations for the parity because we are only representing the connected identity component of the Lorentz group when we seek the usual projective representation. This is because we seek representations of generators, not of the actual group. Parity and time reversal do not lie in the identity component, and are precisely what you need to choose to extend a representation of the component to the whole Lorentz group, but it's is really a *choice*. I'm afraid I don't know of any argument other than this

Comment: I see what you are saying and I guess you are right, but I must say this leaves me rather uneasy... I'll have to give it some thought